# Where is The Maze?

Tags: the-maze-runner

I just finished reading *The Maze Runner* by James Dashner, and I was left with one question, **Where is The Maze?** I can't think of any place on Earth that would be able to have such a huge place so high up, which led me to think if it even is on Earth. Could it be possible that the Griever Hole is like a teleportation device to Earth?

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's not, as we see the maze from the outside. It's set in a post-apocalyptic earth, so it may be a place that does not exist as that now. In addition, there *are* certainly desolate places on earth that are quite large

Comment: There are a few more clues to location in later books (mostly 3). Granted it is vague enough with futuristic technology, but Washington State would be my guess. I'll try to find some more references and make a better answer. Also, the maze is underground.

Comment: @AggieKidd I was doing some more reserach too and realized that it's under WICKED headquarters. Now all you need is to find that.

Comment: Grand Mesa is pretty big.  https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Grand_Mesa

Comment: Read **The Death Cure** and it shall provide the answer you seek...

Answer (score 1):

So, I haven't been able to find anything definitive, so I'll post what evidence I have found and then we can let the speculation begin.  I'll try to hide any and all spoilers as well, but without making the whole answer hidden, I will probably say something along the way, so be forewarned if you are still going through.

In book 1, near the end we get the following information:

> -"Thomas looked up into the sky, felt the water beat against his face—*it was warm, almost hot, had a weird thickness to it*."-
> -"The *next hour* or so was a blur of sights and sounds for Thomas. 
> The driver drove at reckless speeds, *through towns and cities*, the heavy rain obscuring most of the view. Lights and buildings were warped and watery, like something out of a drug-induced hallucination. 
> At one point people outside rushed the bus, their clothes ratty, hair matted to their heads, strange sores like those Thomas had seen on the woman covering their terrified faces." -
> -"*Two hours later*, the bus stopped."

In book 2, we get just a little more information:

> - While the Gladers are in their "Rescue" home - "Three feet from his bed, draped by colorful curtains, a window looked out into a *bright, blinding light*."
>  We don't get an exact travel distance, but the "Subjects" are picked up in what is thought to be Mexico (remember Brenda and Jorge actually know where they are, and they say Mexico) and then there is flight from there.

And some bits from book 3:

> -"No. Jorge got us a *hundred or so miles away*, then landed in a big clearing."  -
>  -"He said he was well rested and he wanted everyone else to take a nap since *it would take a few more hours to reach the city*."- City meaning Denver.
> - "Lawrence woke him up. “Hey, rise and shine, boy. We’ll be there in a few minutes. We’re dropping your butt, then getting the hell out of there. No offense.” -
>  - "The tall, thick pines of the *forest* surrounded Thomas, reaching up to the sky like a wall of majestic towers."
>  - "The air was *crisp and cool* and the forest felt fresh..."-
>  - "He took the last few steps out of the *snowy* clearing and entered the darkness of the thick pines."-

And perhaps the biggest clue we have from book 3:

> - "He’d walked for over an hour when he finally reached the edge of the woods and a wide swatch of barren, rocky earth. Islands of dark brown dirt, devoid of vegetation, dappled the treeless expanse where the snow had been blown away by the wind. Craggy stones of all sizes dotted the land, which sloped toward a sudden drop-off—a huge cliff.
> Beyond that lay the ocean, its deep blue ending on the horizon, where in a sharp line it changed to the light blue of the brilliant sky. And resting on the edge of the cliff, about a mile ahead of him, was WICKED’s headquarters."

Now, it has been made extremely clear that the book is set in the future, with advanced technology, so we don't know how fast flight is, so we may speculate a little bit, but we can do our best.

Firstly, it appears that Wicked's compound is 100 miles plus an additional 3ish hours of flight time from Denver. Unfortunately, we don't know what direction that 100 miles is, so we might just want to approximate about 3 hours of flight time.

We also might be able to assume that flight on the Bergs is relatively similar to modern day airplanes. There are little to no restraints that we hear of on board, as people are able to lounge on couches and such. So, we probably aren't dealing with rocket-fast travel. Also, knowing that the Flat-Trans have been invented, that might give evidence to support a lack of faster flight developement.

Now, from Book 1, we get the idea that the compound may not be more than 3 hours drive from the Scorch. But, comparing the rain from book 1 to the snow in book 3, we are either dealing with quick changes in weather, or perhaps a little discrepancy in the writing as it seems to me that no more than 2-3 months could have passed (2-3 weeks for The Scorch Trials, at most 4-6 weeks for the events in The Death Cure). Again, who knows exactly how weather changes after the Flare, so we may not be able to get too far with this thought.

All we know for certain is that, from The Death Cure, the complex is on a cliff overlooking the ocean. It is also right next to a forest, where there is snow. My first thoughts, and what still seems to fit in my mind is somewhere in northern Washington state or British Columbia. Now, not being a great geographer, I could be a fair way off, but the evidence at least seems to point to somewhere along the Pacific Coast, and a snowy forest would suggest more North than not to me. Again, there is some thought about the "Warm rain" at the end of book 1. Perhaps enough time passed, or an early winter hit. But in my mind, I see that general region. Someone with better knowledge of cliff formations could probably shed more light on more specific possibilities.

Comment: I don't think the book 1 quote about the driving is relevant because the Gladers took a Flat Trans to the scorch.

Comment: @michaelpri I originally added that when I was going to suggest that the HQ might be near the scorch (they seem to wake up at least near the scorch with the bright sun outside), but more and more it seems like there is some disconnect in timelines somewhere instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to the books, the maze is built *underneath* WICKED headquarters (which is somewhere in Alaska-- according to *The Fever Code*.

I have no clue where the maze from the movie would be.

Comment: The Alaska bit is useful since I don't think the previous answer mentioned it. Could you maybe [edit] in a quote from that book which implies/staes it?